# Configure apache to update cached browser files

Tags: apache, caching, browser, webserver

Whenever we update frontend with new changes and restart apache, In order to reflect those changes in browser, browser has to be restarted.

What can be done to reflect those changes without browser restart ?

Configuring Etags in Apache won't help because of multi-server setup.

Comment: Have you tried defining content expire dates using .htaccess?

Comment: @inuka No. Haven't tried that

Comment: another way to do is defining a timestamp of the last updated time of your files such as CSS, JS. This will force the browser to download the latest content. Ex: `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=f4d760dc7b76` Notice the `v=` at the end of the URL.